# How to create const in a loop for require.ensure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, react-router

So I am using `react-router` along with `require.ensure` and webpack to chunk out my routes. However, this has resulted in a *lot* of boilerplate:

```
const getTermsAndConditions = (nextState, cb) => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
    cb(null, require('../containers/TermsAndConditions/TermsAndConditions'))
  }, 'terms')
}
const getThread = (nextState, cb) => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
    cb(null, require('../components/Thread/Thread'))
  }, 'inbox')
}
const getPrivacyPolicy = (nextState, cb) => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
    cb(null, require('../containers/PrivacyPolicy/PrivacyPolicy'))
  }, 'privacy-policy')
}
```

I have about 25 of these declarations in a row, and then in the actual render function:

```
<Route path='privacy' getComponent={getPrivacyPolicy} />
...etc
```

I don't mind having the routes hardcoded as it gives a good idea of the overall layout of the application, but I would like to reduce the boilerplate for the `getPrivacyPolicy` type declarations. How can I do this?

**EDIT**: I've taken after @Michael Jungo's response, but have found the result of the `getComponentFactory` produces functions that still have var names inside them, not hardcoded strings.

Eg:

```
const PrivacyPolicy = getComponentFactory('../containers/PrivacyPolicy/PrivacyPolicy', 'privacy-policy')
```

And then `console.log(PrivacyPolicy)` returns:

```
PrivacyPolicy:  function (nextState, cb) {
  require.ensure([], function (require) {
    return cb(null, require(path))
  }, chunkName)
}
```

So both `path` and `chunkName` are not being replaced by their actual string values...

Comment: Of course there are no hardcoded strings, that's just how closures work! (You can work around this by using `eval`, but I don't suppose you want that). However, since you don't state any explicit dependency anyway, you should be able to adapt your `require` calls to avoid the warning. You might want to [ask a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that.

Comment: @Bergi I wouldn't even know what to ask, do you mind explaining how I would adapt the `require` calls? After executing my webpack build, it looks like those chunks aren't even being generated, so it isn't a trivial error.

Comment: Ah, I missed that webpack tries to parse these things to create chunks. I was assuming that if you used AMD-style `require` (with a callback), the script would at least be executable. Also I find it quite odd that you use `require.ensure` but don't specify any dependencies.

Comment: @Bergi These are components, any deps are listed as `import`s within...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't really reduce the code anymore because `require` and `require.ensure` must receive string literals, variables won't work. It must be known at compile time without program flow analysis. These `getComponent` functions only contain the `require.ensure` statement, so you are stuck writing them all explicitly.

---

## Old answer

You're right, that is a lot of boilerplate, but it is very simple to get rid of most of it because you're pretty much duplicating the same code just with different arguments.

Before going into the code, it is important to know that functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript. This means that you can use a function as a parameter, return value and assign it to a variable, just like any other value. In fact that's exactly what you did, you used a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and assigned it to a variable (e.g. `getPrivacyPolicy`). Well, you used [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is a special syntax for function expressions (with some differences as shown in the documentation). The variable is just to have a reference to it, that you can use later. You don't necessarily need these references, and you can pass them directly to the `getComponent` attribute.

With that in mind you can start refactoring your functions. In your functions everything is the same except for the `path` you require and the `chunkName`. Therefore you're going to create a function that takes `path` and `chunkName` as parameters and **returns a new function** which will be used in `getComponent`.

```
const getComponentFactory = (path, chunkName) => {
  // Return the function that will be passed to getComponent
  return (nextState, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], require => cb(null, require(path)), chunkName);
  };
}
```

Now you can easily create the functions you had by calling `getComponentFactory`, for example:

```
const getThread = getComponentFactory('../components/Thread/Thread', 'inbox');
```

And as mentioned before you don't really need to assign this function to a variable, but you can use it directly in your `Route` if you want to:

```
<Route
  path='inbox'
  getComponent={getComponentFactory('../components/Thread/Thread', 'inbox')}
/>
```

*Note: Don't forget the difference between calling a function and passing it.*

```
console.log(func);       // The function func is printed
console.log(func(args)); // The return value of func is printed
```

Comment: You might even move the `../components/` part and the duplication of the module name into the factory

Comment: @Michael Jungo - this produces the following error `require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`... any idea why?

Comment: @Michael Jungo it looks like this is returning a function which has not replaced `path` and `chunkName` with strings. How do you produce a function with hardcoded strings inside it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've totally forgotten that you're not allowed to have dynamic requires (can't pass `require` a variable). I've updated the answer.